# Prove that the set [a,b] is not well ordered. where a,b are real numbers.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

My Proof:
Assume towards contradiction that [a,b] is well ordered.
(a,b) is a subset of [a,b]. Thus (a,b) has a least element. Let's call this element m. We know that:
$m>a \\
m-a>0 \\
(m-a)/2>0 \\$ 
now we show that
 $a+(m-a)/2<m\\
m+a<2m \\
a<m \\
$

Is this a valid proof? I actually did it sort of intuitively by looking at examples of [0,b] and [1,b] i am not really sure why it works. If someone could explain that ^^

Comment: I don't think so. You're close, & on the right track... but none of your last four lines produce a real in $(a, m)$. Why not just take the average $(a+m)/2$ of $a$ and $m$, then show that $a < (a+m)/2$ and $(a+m)/2 < m$? You already know that $a < m$. Note that the average $(a+m)/2 = a + (m-a)/2$.

Comment: Yeah this is way more clear, I don't know why i have not thought of that. It seems like the average is used a lot in these sort of proofs

Comment: And it makes sense that it would be (used a lot in these sort of proofs): given two distinct numbers, it's a reliable construction of a number strictly between them.

Comment: @BrianO Are you sure that my proof does not work thought. m-a is the "length" between a and m. Divide it by 2 and add m so a+(m-a)/2. Oh this is the average nevermind :P

Comment: I think my proof it sort of the same i just forogt to add a

Comment: That's right :) You just never explicitly say, "a + (m-a)/2 is strictly between a and m, so m can't be the least element of (a,b)". (Noticing your edit: though it's maybe obvious from $(m-a)/2 > 0$, don't forget to say that $a < $ the average, and that the average is in $(a,b)$ so $m$ isn't its least element after all.

Comment: Okay good, i thought i was being retarded. Recently i am having problems with these simple proof. You seem quite knowledgeable, is this a matter of practice or should i change my major? I still can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30954/discussion-between-briano-and-sorfosh).

Comment: I don't want to throw a monkey wrench into this, but shouldn't this be "The order '$\le$' of the ordered field, is not a well ordering of [a, b]" (and for *this* result your proof is perfect if your final line is "a < (a + m)/2 < m").  *BUT* it's my understanding (and I could be wrong) that *if* you accept the axiom of choice, then [a, b]  *is* well-ordered*; just not with the usual '$\le$' ordering.  *Nobody* knows the *what* the well-order is but if the AOC is true one must exist.  (Which is why my professor used to say the AOC is obviously false except when it's obviously true.)

Answer (score 1):

Choose a least element $m\in(a,b)$.  But
$a < {m + a\over 2} < b$; we have found an element smaller than the least element in $(a,b)$, a contradiction.  Therefore $(a,b)$ fails to have a least element.

Answer (score 0):

A proof that does not rely on contradiction is to note that $\left \{ a + \frac{b - a}{n} \;:\; n \in \Bbb N_+\right\}$ is a subset of $[a, b]$ with no least element, as for each $n,\ a+\frac{b - a}{n+1} < a+\frac{b - a}{n}$.

(This is not intended to be an answer to your question, which I hope has been answered to your satisfaction by the contributions of BrianO, ncmathsadist, and fleablood. But it is simply a demonstration that proof by contradiction is not the only approach.)